# How to open a dialog box on click of a dynamic cell value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr>                
                        <td> <ul id="element"></td>

                    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The values in the table are passed from the database using jquery:

```
element += '<li>' + valueOfElement.ELEMENTNAME + '</li>'
```

I want to show some information related to the element name in a dialog box when user clicks the element name. I am new to JavaScript so I don't know how to make a dynamic value clickable and how to open a dialog box on click of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an anchor tag around your element.

```
element += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='myDialogFunction()'>" + valueOfElement.ELEMENTNAME + "</a></li>";
```

To answer your styling question, just add this CSS rule to affect all anchor tags

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

or you can assign your links a class

```
<html>
    <a class='mystyledlink' />
</html>
<style>
    .mystyledlink {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It works fine. Just one more thing.. I don't want the existing formatting to change. Is there any attribute I can use inside the anchor tag itself to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can bind a click event to the elements that will show the dialog box. Without seeing your dialog box or what all that entails I can't really include it but you could do something like this.

```
$('tbody').on('click','li',function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    //do something with value and show dialog box
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is in vanilla JavaScript. You could try something like this: Make use of `addEventListener` to listen for click events on all your clickable cells. You could make use of `document.querySelectorAll` like I did to access all cells.

```js
var tdGroup = document.querySelectorAll( 'td' ),
    i;

for( i = 0; i < tdGroup.length; i++ ){
  tdGroup[ i ].addEventListener( 'click', messages )
}

function messages(){
  alert( 'you clicked' + this.textContent );
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}
th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
td:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click a secondary item of the table for more information</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Technology Field
    </th>
    <th>
      Language
    </th>
    <th>
      Resources
    </th>
    <th>
      Related technologies
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="front-end">
      Front End
    </td>
    <td id="javaScript">
      JavaScript
    </td>
    <td id="stack">
      StackOverflow
    </td>
     <td id="hcs">
      HTML, CSS, SASS
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If any additional questions, please ask here.